# How to store connection string in App.Config when releasing my build?

Tags: c#

Right now I have a small Console application that connects to my database. 
When debugging the application in Visual Studio I can have this in my `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default"
         connectionString="Data Source=*******;Initial Catalog=*******;User Id=*******Password=*******;"/>
</connectionStrings >
```

And I can get the connection string like this:

```
string testConnectiongString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;
```

This works great when running the application In visual studio, how ever when I change to release and move the .exe file onto my laptop or just out of the Visual Studio I get:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

And that is due the connection string, I have to hard code the string in the code for it to work.

So, is there anyway to use `app.config` when releasing my build?

Comment: Did you deploy the app.config besides your executable with the name yourapp.exe.config where yourapp is the actual name of your executable. Both files must be in the same directory.

Comment: Where did you put that App.config? Project of application you're running or maybe some dll? You need first

Comment: App.config becomes yourAppName.exe.config. (look inside the RELEASE/DEBUG folders to find it) This is the file to distribute with your application. Did you do this?

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now, I was not aware of this. But I've read you are supposed to store the connection string inside the app.config so it will hard to get the connection string. But as I need to send the App.Config with the application they can just open the the file with any text editor and get the connection string even easier?

Comment: I don't get it. You store the connection info in the App.Config while you build your application to not HARD-CODE your connection info. You deploy YourAppName.exe.config to adapt your connection info to the customer environment so your program could adapt without requiring changes to its code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR version:

> So, is there anyway to use app.config when releasing my build?

Yes, give users both the `MyApp.exe` and `MyApp.exe.config` files found in `bin\Release` after building.

---

You have two problems:

1. When you're running from Visual Studio, you're running the `.exe` *alongside* a `.config`, but apparently when you're distributing your app you only distribute the `.exe`.
2. If you'd distribute the `.config`, folks could just read it and get the connection string details.

The **first** problem is trivial to solve once you see it.

For context, what you should realize, if you you create a fresh console application and build it both in debug and release, the resulting folder structure will be this:

```
\MyFancyApp\App.config
\MyFancyApp\MyFancyApp.csproj
\MyFancyApp\MyFancyApp.sln
\MyFancyApp\Program.cs

\MyFancyApp\bin
\MyFancyApp\bin\Debug
\MyFancyApp\bin\Debug\MyFancyApp.exe
\MyFancyApp\bin\Debug\MyFancyApp.exe.config       << !

\MyFancyApp\bin\Release
\MyFancyApp\bin\Release\MyFancyApp.exe.config     << !
```

Note that your `app.config` file has been *renamed* to match the executable. You need it to get the connection string. Your application thus includes *both* these files. It would also include additional DLLs if you have NuGet packages or secondary class library projects that compile to DLLs.

The **second** problem is less trivial to solve. Here are two potential solutions:

1. [Encrypt the `.config` section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx). However, that only prevents casual *reading* of the config file.
2. Do not store the credentials in the config, but ask the user to input them. You could use `#IF DEBUG` instructions to skip that bit when developing.

There are several other options of course, but I think discussing those may be out of scope for this question or SO in general.

---

PS. If you're looking to prevent the actual `NullReferenceException` you're getting, you could check for `null`, e.g.:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"] == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Missing connection string configuration");
        Console.ReadKey();
        return;
    }

    string testConnectiongString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;
    Console.WriteLine("Doing work...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```